# RecyclerView part of ScrollView

Tags: android, xml, xamarin

I have a RecyclerView as the bottom view, along with some other views on top:

[image: Screenshot]

I want to scroll the entire view (1), not just the RecyclerView (2).

I have managed to get it to work, but not flawlessly. XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            ...

            <View
                style="@style/Divider"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewNote"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Two problems:

1. Scrolling in the recyclerview isn't smooth, in the sense that when I lift up my finger, the scrolling stops. No accelerated scroll, or whatever you call it.
2. When I remove items from the recyclerview, its height remains the same. Meaning I have empty space where the images once was.

Comment: I have the same issue, I get data for recycler from the server and I've checked, the reason recycler is not smooth, is that it's inside a scrollview and gets all images from the server at once and not visible item! I don't have any solutions yet, do you have one?!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with your example

> Scrolling in the `recyclerview` isn't smooth, in the sense that when I
>   lift up my finger, the scrolling stops. No accelerated scroll, or
>   whatever you call it.

Even I noticed that. I think there are some restrictions when you use nested scrolling as it has to handle both scrolls.

> When I remove items from the `recyclerview`, its height remains the
>   same. Meaning I have empty space where the images once was.

The white space is because of the `padding` you have applied to the `linear layout` of `recyclerview`. Event though you remove all items from recyclerview the padding of parent `linear layout` remains same and so is the whitespace.

Comment: Yeah, seems like such a simple problem. I will try to experiment with some of the many other views available. Maybe I also need to override some of the scrollbehaviors.

Comment: @raze Yes. And what about white space. Is it the case which I explained in my answer?

Comment: No, that didn't help. The view is still as height as if the image was there, even though I have wrap_content and removed the padding. Need to refresh the layout somehow.

Comment: @raze have you used `notifyDataSetChanged()` on `recyclerview adapter` after removing the items from it? If not then use it

Comment: I use NotifyItemRemoved(position). Less resourceful, and comes with animations. It works on other recyclerviews that I have.

Answer (score -1):

use nestedScrollView

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
  </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: But then I get the unwanted behavior.

Comment: keep it inside RelativeLayout not inside LinearLayout

Comment: If you are certain that this works, can you please provide a full layout? I'm moving backwards now :)